# Python Pandas read_csv skip rows but keep header

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm having trouble figuring out how to skip n rows in a csv file but keep the header which is the 1 row.

What I want to do is iterate but keep the header from the first row.  `skiprows` makes the header the first row after the skipped rows.  What is the best way of doing this?

```
data = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep='|', header=0, skiprows=10, nrows=10)
```

Answer (score 171, accepted):

You can pass a list of row numbers to `skiprows` instead of an integer.

By giving the function the integer 10, you're just skipping the first 10 lines.

To keep the first row 0 (as the header) and then skip everything else up to row 10, you can write:

```
pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep='|', skiprows=range(1, 10))
```

---

### Other ways to skip rows using `read_csv`

The two main ways to control which rows `read_csv` uses are the `header` or `skiprows` parameters.

Supose we have the following CSV file with one column:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

In each of the examples below, this file is `f = io.StringIO("\n".join("abcdef"))`.

- Read all lines as values (no header, defaults to integers)

  ```
  >>> pd.read_csv(f, header=None)
     0
  0  a
  1  b
  2  c
  3  d
  4  e
  5  f
  ```
- Use a particular row as the header (skip all lines before that):

  ```
  >>> pd.read_csv(f, header=3)
     d
  0  e
  1  f
  ```
- Use a multiple rows as the header creating a MultiIndex (skip all lines before the last specified header line):

  ```
  >>> pd.read_csv(f, header=[2, 4])                                                                                                                                                                        
     c
     e
  0  f
  ```
- Skip N rows from the start of the file (the first row that's not skipped is the header):

  ```
  >>> pd.read_csv(f, skiprows=3)                                                                                                                                                                      
     d
  0  e
  1  f
  ```
- Skip one or more rows by giving the row indices (the first row that's not skipped is the header):

  ```
  >>> pd.read_csv(f, skiprows=[2, 4])                                                                                                                                                                      
     a
  0  b
  1  d
  2  f
  ```

Answer (score 18):

Great answers already. Consider this generalized scenario:

Say your xls/csv has junk rows in the top 2 rows (row #0,1). Row #2 (3rd row) is the real header and you want to load 10 rows starting from row #50 (i.e 51st row).

Here's the snippet:

`pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=2, skiprows=range(3, 50), nrows=10)`

Answer (score 4):

To expand on @AlexRiley's answer, the `skiprows` argument takes a list of numbers which determines what rows to skip. So:

```
pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep='|', skiprows=range(1, 10))
```

is the same as:

```
pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep='|', skiprows=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
```

The best way to go about ignoring specific rows would be to create your ignore list (either manually or with a function like `range` that returns a list of integers) and pass it to `skiprows`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're iterating through a long csv file, you can use the [chunksize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114/how-do-i-read-a-large-csv-file-with-pandas) argument. If for some reason you need to manually step through it, you can try the following as long as you know how many iterations you need to go through:

```
for i in range(num_iters):
    pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep='|', header=0, 
                 skiprows = range(i*10 + 1, (i+1)*10), nrows=10)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to skip/drop specific rows, say the first 3 rows (i.e. 0,1,2) and then 2 more rows (i.e. 4,5). You can use the following to retain the header row:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_in, delimiter='\t', skiprows=[0,1,2,4,5], encoding='utf-16', usecols=cols)
```