# pandas - Why am I unable to skip rows using the "skiprows" parameter of Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So, have a look at the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def answer_one():

    energy = pd.read_excel(io = "Energy Indicators.xls", header = 9, parse_cols = "C:F", skip_footer = 38)
    return energy

answer_one()
```

It produces the following output:

[image]

Now, when I make a little modification to the code, as below, it changes the output completely:

```
def answer_one():

    energy = pd.read_excel(io = "Energy Indicators.xls", header = 9, parse_cols = "C:F", skip_footer = 38, skiprows = 8)
    return energy

answer_one()
```

The output that I get is as follows:

[image]

Depending upon the argument that I give to the "skiprows" parameter, the output changes itself. I am unable to understand why does changing the value of "skiprows" affect the headers of the dataframe, when we are keeping the argument of the "headers"parameter unchanged? Please find the data file (.xlsx file) [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=17Pb50j1RlghSspsjcQV3_RVG-nCIB9lg)

Any help please? I use Pandas v0.19.2. Also, please don't tag my question as "duplicate". I lose points man. I tried reasonably well to find an existing question, but could not.

Comment: What is desired output? do you want index from first column country or default index - `0,1,2` ? And what columns names? Need units or `['Energy Supply', 'Energy Supply per capita', 'Renewable Electricity Production']` ?

Comment: The desired output is a DataFrame consisting of respective columns and their headers being "Country", "Energy Supply", "Energy Supply per capita", "% Renewable". I am struggling to skip the header and the footer, but I am unable to.

Comment: OK, then check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need skip all rows by positions defined in `list`, row `10` is not in list, because data for `Andorra`. Data (row `1-8`) before position defined in `header` (`9`) are excluded by default .

Also `parse_cols` was replaced by `usecols`, because warning:

> FutureWarning: the 'parse_cols' keyword is deprecated, use 'usecols' instead
>     parse_cols = "C:F"

```
df=pd.read_excel('Energy Indicators.xls',
                  sheet_name='Energy',
                  skiprows=[10,12,13,14,15,16,17],
                  skipfooter=38,
                  header=9,
                  usecols=[2,3,4,5]  #parse_cols = "C:F"
                 )
print (df.head())

          Country Energy Supply Energy Supply per capita  \
0         Andorra             9                      121   
1     Afghanistan           321                       10   
2         Albania           102                       35   
3         Algeria          1959                       51   
4  American Samoa           ...                      ...   

   Renewable Electricity Production  
0                         88.695650  
1                         78.669280  
2                        100.000000  
3                          0.551010  
4                          0.641026
```

Comment: Well, since I am using Pandas v0.19.2, "parse_cols" is the one to use. "usecols" won't work at all.

Comment: Yes, solution is for pandas `0.22.0`. Is possible upgrade?

Comment: Nope. Tried your code, but doesn't work. I get countries as the index, and only two columns: "Energy Supply per capita", "Renewable Electricity Production"

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Since I am running my program on a website, the server has everything installed. I am forced to work with 0.19.2.

Comment: do you omit `index_col` parameter?

Comment: Can you please open a chat with me?

Comment: OK, but first is possible test `parse_cols = "C:F"` instead `parse_cols` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162647/discussion-between-archan-joshi-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 6):

When you skip the first 8 rows, you skip the row that has your header information, and the 9th row becomes your header. Instead of skipping the first 8 rows, try

```
skiprows=range(1, 9)
```

In the documentation, skiprows allows an iterable of which rows to skip. There is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27325652/python-pandas-read-csv-skip-rows-but-keep-header/27325729) regarding csv files and the `read_csv()` method already on StackOverflow.

Comment: I've used skiprows=range(1, nrows_to_skip-1)

Comment: You almost certainly want `range(1, nrows_to_skip + 1)` instead.